# apply one textures to others

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm modeled a a tree before some days and right now I'm trying to texture the leafs. Is it possible to just texture one of the hexagons as a leaf and to apply the texture of this one to the others ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you created the tree with Sapling and didn't change UV map then most likely you don't need to anything other than usual adding material and including desired image texture/s there. All the leaves should be textured the same according to the created UV map

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are these made using sapling addon? If yes then just create a shader, and move all of the uvs and scale them in the uv editor. It will automatically apply the texture to all of them. If not yhen i think you should use sapling addon.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the same mesh, it would be very dificult, but you can separate the leafts into individual objects, that way you can put the same texture to all of them.

In order to do so, you must select all the leafts whit <kbd>A</kbd> and then Press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose by Loose Parts. then you can asing the same material to all the individual leafts.

It should be posible to use unwrap and uv textures to return them to the same object, but i'm  not so sure, so lets keep it that way, good luck.

Comment: Note that separating several thousands leaves into different objects will take quite a bit of calculations, not to mention it will slow down the viewport performance. By default Sapling addon for creating trees unwraps the leaves making each leaf using all the texture space.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! i really I appreciate it !!! I really believe that it will work. My laptop is too slow for that :*(, and its not working hard enough. Do you got a tip for me what I can do ?

Comment: Mr Zak I made my tree with the add on, what do I need to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Select all Leafs, hit P and select "by loose parts" to make all leafs to an individual object
2. Select all the new leaf-objects,hit alt+ctrl+shift+c and select "origin to geometry" to fix the origin of each leaf-object
3. If all leafs should have the same geometry, select all leaf-objects, hit ctrl+l and select "Object Data" to make each leaf-object use the same mesh data-block
4. Select one leaf-object and unwrap the mesh
5. Select all leaf-objects with the unwrapped one as the active one, hit ctrl+l again and select "Transfer UV Maps" to copy the UV-map to every leaf
6. Select one leaf-object and add a material to it
7. Select all leaf-objects with the one with the material as the active one, hit ctrl+l once again and select "Materials" to copy the material to every leaf

Comment: I see a problem with my answer: the resulting leafs will all point in the same direction.

Comment: ohh thats not good. But a pretty good idea! Thank you anyway :)